# How to Use Map<STRING, OBJECT> dataType (column) in flinkSql

Tags: apache, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

`I am fairly new the flinkSql and for one of our use cases, we need to define a column of type Map<String, Object>. The data is received in json format via and need to materialized and send forward to a new kafka topic. I am trying to formulate a custom user defined function too with
but running into error. Is there an alternate way to define a generic object type in flink sql which is equivalent to Object class in java.

Here is a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <TABLE_NAME> 
(     org                     VARCHAR,     
      displayName             VARCHAR NOT NULL,     
      ....
      ....
      attributes              MAP<STRING, BINARY>,
      ....     
      created                 TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3),
      PRIMARY KEY (org, id) NOT ENFORCED ) 
WITH (     
'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',     
'topic' = '${output_topic_name}',     
'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${sink_kafka_servers}',     
'value.format' = 'json',     
'key.format' = 'json',     
'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',     
'properties.num.partitions' = '${sink_properties_num_partitions}',     
'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',     
'sink.parallelism' = '${sink_parallelism}',     
'sink.buffer-flush.interval' = '${sink_flush_interval}',     
'sink.buffer-flush.max-rows' = '${sink_flush_max_rows}' );
```

User defined function

```
@FunctionHint(
output = @DataTypeHint(value = "MAP\<STRING, OBJECT\>", bridgedTo = MapData.class))
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class JsonToMapData extends ScalarFunction {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonToMapData.class);
    private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    public MapData eval(String json){
        Map<StringData, BinaryRawValueData> genericMapData;
        ....
        ....

}
```

Error while running the server
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlIdentifier: OBJECT java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlIdentifier: OBJECT`

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Tried using BINARY and ROW as an alternate for column type with Map<STRING, ROW<>> and MAP<STRING, RAW> but none of them seems to work either`